# Using Multiple Worklight 6.0 WAR Installs with WebSphere Analytics

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, worklight-analytics

When using the WebSphere Analytics Platform, can multiple Worklight 6.0 application WAR installations (i.e. consoles) point to a single instance of the Analytics piece?  Or, do you have to install a separate Analytics instance for each WAR?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have more than one WAR pointing to the same IWAP (IBM WebSphere Analytics Platform) instance; you also can point to different IWAP instances if you want to. When you search in IWAP, it will display from which application the information in the search came from.

Comment: Please keep in mind that in the Worklight Console there is an Analytics tab, and you can only view one IWAP server at a time. The server you are viewing is specified on the JNDI properties of the server, namely wl.analytics.url.

Comment: To see how to set/change the JNDI properties for the Worklight server, see the documentation: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fadmin%2Ft_using_JNDI_lookup_to_override_WL_properties.html&resultof%3D%2522%256a%256e%2564%2569%2522%2520